# Trying to run a Scheduled command every month on 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 10th with"schtasks "on windows, it shows error "Invalid value for /D option."

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

## Problem : What I am trying to do

- Trying to Task Scheduled on Windows to run PHP Script
- The Script should Execute on Months like "JAN, FEB"
- It should run only on Specific Dates such as. 23rd and 24th,
- At a particular time 1:59

## Example:  Command which I am trying to run.

```
schtasks.exe /Create /TN "BackupPro" /TR "C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\backuprogit\backuppro/cron.php" /SC MONTHLY /M "JAN, FEB" /D "23,24"  /ST 19:59
```

## Error

```
ERROR: Invalid value for /D option. Type "SCHTASKS /CREATE /?" for usage.
```

## Description.

We can setup this task the way described above through the Windows "Task Scheduler" interface and using trigger type "Monthly" but when I try to achieve the same through command.

### Screenshot of the Task Scheduler > Create Basic Task.

[image]

## What I need help with.

Please help to setup a similar task but through command line.